# Gitlab - webroot directory

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have a gitlab droplet from the one-click installs on digital ocean running. I am looking to secure it with letsencrypt from this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

Where is the webroot for gitlab? I would usually look in /var/www/... but there is no such thing. I need to run this script: `./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/usr/share/nginx/html -d example.com -d www.example.com`

Where is gitlab's embedded /usr/share/nginx/html directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu trusty and this path worked for me

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
```

I also can recommend using `certbot`. For me it was much easier and I followed this [tutorial](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-nginx).

Comment: Ahh thanks for that. Yeah certbot does seem to be an easier process